# EADDRINUSE with Node.js on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, port, openshift

Writing a test application in Node.js running on OpenShift and it currently will not start.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/env node

var http = require('http');

var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(ip, port);
console.log('Server running');
```

I get the error

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1003:19)
at listen (net.js:1044:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1104:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52854c6f4382ec071400051d/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:11:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
```

Which seems to mean I can't bind to the port. I've found various information on why this might be but none of it seems relevant - it all seems related to permissions but surely the point of process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_* is I have permission to bind to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means some other process is using your port `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`. EACCESS would mean permission denied, not EADDRINUSE. Try changing to unused ports like 8080. You can check used ports with :

```
netstat -tulpn
netstat -tulpn | grep :$OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT //filter by your port
```

Comment: Access is denied